# Python: extract inside values from unstructured list with one element

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray, flatten

In result of opening `.mat` (MatLab) file, I received unstructured list with one element as:

```
list_1 = [(np.array(['charge'], dtype='<U6'), np.array([[24]], dtype=float), np.array([[2.0080e+03, 4.0000e+00, 2.0000e+00, 1.3000e+01, 8.0000e+00,
         1.7921e+01]]), np.array([[(np.array([[3.87301722, 3.47939356, 4.00058782, 4.01239519, 4.01970806]]), np.array([[-1.20066070e-03, -4.03026848e+00,  1.51273065e+00,
          1.50906328e+00,  1.51131819e+00,  1.51277913e+00,
          1.51183834e+00,  1.51024540e+00,  1.50779576e+00,
          1.50732203e+00,  1.51022594e+00,  1.51185336e+00]]), np.array([[0.000000e+00, 2.532000e+00, 5.500000e+00, 8.344000e+00,
         1.112500e+01, 1.389100e+01, 1.667200e+01, 1.950000e+01,
         2.228200e+01, 2.506300e+01, 2.782800e+01, 3.064100e+01,
         3.345300e+01, 3.621900e+01, 3.973500e+01, 4.257800e+01]]))]],
       dtype=[('Res1', 'O'), ('Rea2', 'O'), ('Res3', 'O')]))]
```

I would like to extract each `np.array` to separate `Variable`.
Expected result is:

```
var1 = np.array([[2.0080e+03, 4.0000e+00, 2.0000e+00, 1.3000e+01, 8.0000e+00,
         1.7921e+01]])
var2 = np.array([[(np.array([[3.87301722, 3.47939356, 4.00058782, 4.01239519, 4.01970806]])
var3 = np.array([[-1.20066070e-03, -4.03026848e+00,  1.51273065e+00,
          1.50906328e+00,  1.51131819e+00,  1.51277913e+00,
          1.51183834e+00,  1.51024540e+00,  1.50779576e+00,
          1.50732203e+00,  1.51022594e+00,  1.51185336e+00]])
var4 = np.array([[0.000000e+00, 2.532000e+00, 5.500000e+00, 8.344000e+00,
         1.112500e+01, 1.389100e+01, 1.667200e+01, 1.950000e+01,
         2.228200e+01, 2.506300e+01, 2.782800e+01, 3.064100e+01,
         3.345300e+01, 3.621900e+01, 3.973500e+01, 4.257800e+01]])
```

I tried to move this `list_1` to `np.array` and make `np.squeeze(array_1).item()`, but this is wrong way.

How is it possible to parse element in such list? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A copy-n-paste produces a 1 element list:

```
In [591]: list_1 = [(np.array(['charge'], dtype='<U6'), np.array([[24]], dtype=float), np.array([
     ...: [2.0080e+03, 4.0000e+00, 2.0000e+00, 1.3000e+01, 8.0000e+00, 
     ...:          1.7921e+01]]), np.array([[(np.array([[3.87301722, 3.47939356, 4.00058782, 4.01
     ...: 239519, 4.01970806]]), np.array([[-1.20066070e-03, -4.03026848e+00,  1.51273065e+00, 
     ...:           1.50906328e+00,  1.51131819e+00,  1.51277913e+00, 
     ...:           1.51183834e+00,  1.51024540e+00,  1.50779576e+00, 
     ...:           1.50732203e+00,  1.51022594e+00,  1.51185336e+00]]), np.array([[0.000000e+00,
     ...:  2.532000e+00, 5.500000e+00, 8.344000e+00, 
     ...:          1.112500e+01, 1.389100e+01, 1.667200e+01, 1.950000e+01, 
     ...:          2.228200e+01, 2.506300e+01, 2.782800e+01, 3.064100e+01, 
     ...:          3.345300e+01, 3.621900e+01, 3.973500e+01, 4.257800e+01]]))]], 
     ...:        dtype=[('Res1', 'O'), ('Rea2', 'O'), ('Res3', 'O')]))]                          
In [592]: len(list_1)                                                                            
Out[592]: 1
```

That element is a 4 element tuple:

```
In [593]: list_1[0]                                                                              
Out[593]: 
(array(['charge'], dtype='<U6'),
 array([[24.]]),
 array([[2.0080e+03, 4.0000e+00, 2.0000e+00, 1.3000e+01, 8.0000e+00,
         1.7921e+01]]),
 array([[(array([[3.87301722, 3.47939356, 4.00058782, 4.01239519, 4.01970806]]), array([[-1.20066070e-03, -4.03026848e+00,  1.51273065e+00,
          1.50906328e+00,  1.51131819e+00,  1.51277913e+00,
          1.51183834e+00,  1.51024540e+00,  1.50779576e+00,
          1.50732203e+00,  1.51022594e+00,  1.51185336e+00]]), array([[ 0.   ,  2.532,  5.5  ,  8.344, 11.125, 13.891, 16.672, 19.5  ,
         22.282, 25.063, 27.828, 30.641, 33.453, 36.219, 39.735, 42.578]]))]],
       dtype=[('Res1', 'O'), ('Rea2', 'O'), ('Res3', 'O')]))
In [594]: type(_)                                                                                
Out[594]: tuple
In [595]: len(__)                                                                                
Out[595]: 4
```

which we can then unpack into 4 variables:

```
In [596]: var1,var2,var3,var4=list_1[0]                                                          
In [597]: var1                                                                                   
Out[597]: array(['charge'], dtype='<U6')      # a string
In [598]: var2                                                                                   
Out[598]: array([[24.]])                      # a number, (1,1) array
In [599]: var3                                                                                   
Out[599]: 
array([[2.0080e+03, 4.0000e+00, 2.0000e+00, 1.3000e+01, 8.0000e+00,
        1.7921e+01]])
```

`var3` was a matrix, here a (1,6) numeric array.

```
In [600]: var4                                                                                   
Out[600]: 
array([[(array([[3.87301722, 3.47939356, 4.00058782, 4.01239519, 4.01970806]]), array([[-1.20066070e-03, -4.03026848e+00,  1.51273065e+00,
         1.50906328e+00,  1.51131819e+00,  1.51277913e+00,
         1.51183834e+00,  1.51024540e+00,  1.50779576e+00,
         1.50732203e+00,  1.51022594e+00,  1.51185336e+00]]), array([[ 0.   ,  2.532,  5.5  ,  8.344, 11.125, 13.891, 16.672, 19.5  ,
        22.282, 25.063, 27.828, 30.641, 33.453, 36.219, 39.735, 42.578]]))]],
      dtype=[('Res1', 'O'), ('Rea2', 'O'), ('Res3', 'O')])
```

This last one is complex; I think this was a `struct` in MATLAB.  Here is is a (1,1) shape (1 element, 2d), structured array with 3 fields, each of which contains arrays (object dtype).

```
In [601]: var4.shape                                                                             
Out[601]: (1, 1)
In [602]: var4.dtype                                                                             
Out[602]: dtype([('Res1', 'O'), ('Rea2', 'O'), ('Res3', 'O')])
```

which we can reference with:

```
In [603]: var4[0,0]['Res1']                                                                      
Out[603]: array([[3.87301722, 3.47939356, 4.00058782, 4.01239519, 4.01970806]])
In [604]: var4[0,0]['Rea2']                                                                      
Out[604]: 
array([[-1.20066070e-03, -4.03026848e+00,  1.51273065e+00,
         1.50906328e+00,  1.51131819e+00,  1.51277913e+00,
         1.51183834e+00,  1.51024540e+00,  1.50779576e+00,
         1.50732203e+00,  1.51022594e+00,  1.51185336e+00]])
In [605]: var4[0,0]['Res3']                                                                      
Out[605]: 
array([[ 0.   ,  2.532,  5.5  ,  8.344, 11.125, 13.891, 16.672, 19.5  ,
        22.282, 25.063, 27.828, 30.641, 33.453, 36.219, 39.735, 42.578]])
```

---

The single element of `var4` taken out of the (1,1) MATLAB shape:

```
In [631]: var4[0,0]                                                                              
Out[631]: 
(array([[3.87301722, 3.47939356, 4.00058782, 4.01239519, 4.01970806]]), array([[-1.20066070e-03, -4.03026848e+00,  1.51273065e+00,
         1.50906328e+00,  1.51131819e+00,  1.51277913e+00,
         1.51183834e+00,  1.51024540e+00,  1.50779576e+00,
         1.50732203e+00,  1.51022594e+00,  1.51185336e+00]]), array([[ 0.   ,  2.532,  5.5  ,  8.344, 11.125, 13.891, 16.672, 19.5  ,
        22.282, 25.063, 27.828, 30.641, 33.453, 36.219, 39.735, 42.578]]))
```

Extract that into a tuple:

```
In [632]: var4[0,0].tolist()                                                                     
Out[632]: 
(array([[3.87301722, 3.47939356, 4.00058782, 4.01239519, 4.01970806]]),
 array([[-1.20066070e-03, -4.03026848e+00,  1.51273065e+00,
          1.50906328e+00,  1.51131819e+00,  1.51277913e+00,
          1.51183834e+00,  1.51024540e+00,  1.50779576e+00,
          1.50732203e+00,  1.51022594e+00,  1.51185336e+00]]),
 array([[ 0.   ,  2.532,  5.5  ,  8.344, 11.125, 13.891, 16.672, 19.5  ,
         22.282, 25.063, 27.828, 30.641, 33.453, 36.219, 39.735, 42.578]]))
In [633]: type(_)                                                                                
Out[633]: tuple
```

Without the [0,0], `tolist` would give us a couple of layers of list nesting, `[[(....)]]`.

The structured array names are:

```
In [634]: var4.dtype.names                                                                       
Out[634]: ('Res1', 'Rea2', 'Res3')
```

and a dictionary combining those names and the arrays in [632]:

```
In [636]: dd = {name:val for name, val in zip(var4.dtype.names, var4[0,0].tolist())}             
In [637]: dd                                                                                     
Out[637]: 
{'Res1': array([[3.87301722, 3.47939356, 4.00058782, 4.01239519, 4.01970806]]),
 'Rea2': array([[-1.20066070e-03, -4.03026848e+00,  1.51273065e+00,
          1.50906328e+00,  1.51131819e+00,  1.51277913e+00,
          1.51183834e+00,  1.51024540e+00,  1.50779576e+00,
          1.50732203e+00,  1.51022594e+00,  1.51185336e+00]]),
 'Res3': array([[ 0.   ,  2.532,  5.5  ,  8.344, 11.125, 13.891, 16.672, 19.5  ,
         22.282, 25.063, 27.828, 30.641, 33.453, 36.219, 39.735, 42.578]])}
In [638]: dd["Rea2"]                                                                             
Out[638]: 
array([[-1.20066070e-03, -4.03026848e+00,  1.51273065e+00,
         1.50906328e+00,  1.51131819e+00,  1.51277913e+00,
         1.51183834e+00,  1.51024540e+00,  1.50779576e+00,
         1.50732203e+00,  1.51022594e+00,  1.51185336e+00]])
```

Compare this last access with `In[604]`.  Same thing, slightly different indexing.

Comment: yes, it works but the question is that how is it possible to automate it? not manually detect that there are 4 variables need. If I have list of one element in view of tuple with 10000 np.arrays inside than I would not manually create 10000 variables for assigning to each of it the responded np.array(). Other words, how to automatically detect that there are 10000 np.arrays inside of this tuple?  Thank you for the idea anyway!

Comment: In Python we don't normally try to assign objects to a large number of distinct variables (with names like `var1`,`var2`,...).  We use lists and tuples (and if needed dictionaries) of objects.  I've added some code to show how `var4` can be transformed into a tuple or dictionary.